# Extract measurement data values of column r

Tags: regex, r

I am just learning regex right now in R. I have a sample data frame as shown below:

```
col1 <- c('1/2 in. x 1/2 in. x 3/4 ft. Copper Pressure Cup', 'Ensemble 60 in. x 43-1/2 in. x 54-1/4 in. 3-piece',
'2-3/4 in. x 4-1/2 in. Heavy-Duty',
'1/4-20 x 2 in. Forged Steel ',
'1/2-Amp Slo-Blo GMA Fuse',
'3/4 in. x 12 in. x 24 in. White Thermally',
'12.0 oz. of weight',
'1.4 fl. oz. of liquid',
'14 gal. tall',
'Sahara Wood 47 in. Long x 12-1/8 in. Deep x 1-11/16 in. Height',
'1/25 HP Cast Iron ',
'1/2 in., 3/4 in. and 1 in. PVC ',
'24-3/4 in. x 48-3/4 in. x 1-1/4 in. Faux Windsor',
'8 oz. -200 Pot Of Cream',
'5/8 in. dia. x 25 ft. Water ',
'18.5 / 30.5 in. Brushed Nickel',
'57-1/2 in. x 70-5/16 in. Semi-Framed',
'2-1/4 HP Router',
'12-Volt Lithium-Ion Cordless 3/8 in.',
'12-Gauge 24-5/8 in. Strap ',
'7-3/4 in. Wigan Ceiling',
'1 qt. B-I-N ',
'3/8 in. O.D. x 1/4 in. NPTF',
'2-1/2 in. Long x 5/8 in. Diameter Spring',
'1/4 x 3 in. Heat-Shrink ',
'4-White PVC End',
'41000 Series Non-Vented Range',
'Revival 1-Spray 5-Katalyst Air',
'180-Degree White Outdoor',
'3/8 x 3 Hand Scraped ',
'67-Qt. Jug',
'35-77-7/8 in. White',
'-16 tpi x 4 in. Stainless Steel',
'3-21 degree Full')

df <- data.frame(col1 = col1)

df
                                                             col1
1                 1/2 in. x 1/2 in. x 3/4 ft. Copper Pressure Cup
2               Ensemble 60 in. x 43-1/2 in. x 54-1/4 in. 3-piece
3                                2-3/4 in. x 4-1/2 in. Heavy-Duty
4                                    1/4-20 x 2 in. Forged Steel 
5                                        1/2-Amp Slo-Blo GMA Fuse
6                       3/4 in. x 12 in. x 24 in. White Thermally
7                                              12.0 oz. of weight
8                                           1.4 fl. oz. of liquid
9                                                    14 gal. tall
10 Sahara Wood 47 in. Long x 12-1/8 in. Deep x 1-11/16 in. Height
11                                             1/25 HP Cast Iron 
12                                1/2 in., 3/4 in. and 1 in. PVC 
13               24-3/4 in. x 48-3/4 in. x 1-1/4 in. Faux Windsor
14                                        8 oz. -200 Pot Of Cream
15                                   5/8 in. dia. x 25 ft. Water 
16                                 18.5 / 30.5 in. Brushed Nickel
17                           57-1/2 in. x 70-5/16 in. Semi-Framed
18                                                2-1/4 HP Router
19                           12-Volt Lithium-Ion Cordless 3/8 in.
20                                     12-Gauge 24-5/8 in. Strap 
21                                        7-3/4 in. Wigan Ceiling
22                                                   1 qt. B-I-N 
23                                    3/8 in. O.D. x 1/4 in. NPTF
24                       2-1/2 in. Long x 5/8 in. Diameter Spring
25                                       1/4 x 3 in. Heat-Shrink 
26                                                4-White PVC End
27                                  41000 Series Non-Vented Range
28                                 Revival 1-Spray 5-Katalyst Air
29                                       180-Degree White Outdoor
30                                          3/8 x 3 Hand Scraped 
31                                                     67-Qt. Jug
32                                            35-77-7/8 in. White
33                                -16 tpi x 4 in. Stainless Steel
34                                               3-21 degree Full
```

I would like to extract all the measurement data from col1 and add it to col2. 
I tried the following:

```
df$col2 <- str_extract(df$col1, '([[:digit:]]*\\/?\\.?\\-?[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+(in|ft)\\.[[:space:]]*x*)')
```

And the results are as follows:

```
 col1      col2
1                 1/2 in. x 1/2 in. x 3/4 ft. Copper Pressure Cup 1/2 in. x
2               Ensemble 60 in. x 43-1/2 in. x 54-1/4 in. 3-piece  60 in. x
3                                2-3/4 in. x 4-1/2 in. Heavy-Duty 3/4 in. x
4                                    1/4-20 x 2 in. Forged Steel     2 in. 
5                                        1/2-Amp Slo-Blo GMA Fuse      <NA>
6                       3/4 in. x 12 in. x 24 in. White Thermally 3/4 in. x
7                                              12.0 oz. of weight      <NA>
8                                           1.4 fl. oz. of liquid      <NA>
9                                                    14 gal. tall      <NA>
10 Sahara Wood 47 in. Long x 12-1/8 in. Deep x 1-11/16 in. Height   47 in. 
11                                             1/25 HP Cast Iron       <NA>
12                                1/2 in., 3/4 in. and 1 in. PVC    1/2 in.
13               24-3/4 in. x 48-3/4 in. x 1-1/4 in. Faux Windsor 3/4 in. x
14                                        8 oz. -200 Pot Of Cream      <NA>
15                                   5/8 in. dia. x 25 ft. Water   5/8 in. 
16                                 18.5 / 30.5 in. Brushed Nickel 30.5 in. 
17                           57-1/2 in. x 70-5/16 in. Semi-Framed 1/2 in. x
18                                                2-1/4 HP Router      <NA>
19                           12-Volt Lithium-Ion Cordless 3/8 in.   3/8 in.
20                                     12-Gauge 24-5/8 in. Strap   5/8 in. 
21                                        7-3/4 in. Wigan Ceiling  3/4 in. 
22                                                   1 qt. B-I-N       <NA>
23                                    3/8 in. O.D. x 1/4 in. NPTF  3/8 in. 
24                       2-1/2 in. Long x 5/8 in. Diameter Spring  1/2 in. 
25                                       1/4 x 3 in. Heat-Shrink     3 in. 
26                                                4-White PVC End      <NA>
27                                  41000 Series Non-Vented Range      <NA>
28                                 Revival 1-Spray 5-Katalyst Air      <NA>
29                                       180-Degree White Outdoor      <NA>
30                                          3/8 x 3 Hand Scraped       <NA>
31                                                     67-Qt. Jug      <NA>
32                                            35-77-7/8 in. White  7/8 in. 
33                                -16 tpi x 4 in. Stainless Steel    4 in. 
34                                               3-21 degree Full      <NA>
```

However, I would want to see results like:

```
df
                                                             col1                                               col2
1                 1/2 in. x 1/2 in. x 3/4 ft. Copper Pressure Cup                        1/2 in. x 1/2 in. x 3/4 ft.
2               Ensemble 60 in. x 43-1/2 in. x 54-1/4 in. 3-piece                   60 in. x 43-1/2 in. x 54-1/4 in.
3                                2-3/4 in. x 4-1/2 in. Heavy-Duty                              2-3/4 in. x 4-1/2 in.
4                                    1/4-20 x 2 in. Forged Steel                                      1/4-20 x 2 in.
5                                        1/2-Amp Slo-Blo GMA Fuse                                            1/2-Amp
6                       3/4 in. x 12 in. x 24 in. White Thermally                          3/4 in. x 12 in. x 24 in.
7                                              12.0 oz. of weight                                           12.0 oz.
8                                           1.4 fl. oz. of liquid                                        1.4 fl. oz.
9                                                    14 gal. tall                                            14 gal.
10 Sahara Wood 47 in. Long x 12-1/8 in. Deep x 1-11/16 in. Height 47 in. Long x 12-1/8 in. Deep x 1-11/16 in. Height
11                                             1/25 HP Cast Iron                                            1/25 HP 
12                                1/2 in., 3/4 in. and 1 in. PVC                          1/2 in., 3/4 in. and 1 in.
13               24-3/4 in. x 48-3/4 in. x 1-1/4 in. Faux Windsor               24-3/4 in. x 48-3/4 in. x 1-1/4 in. 
14                                        8 oz. -200 Pot Of Cream                                              8 oz.
15                                   5/8 in. dia. x 25 ft. Water                               5/8 in. dia. x 25 ft.
16                                 18.5 / 30.5 in. Brushed Nickel                                    18.5 / 30.5 in.
17                           57-1/2 in. x 70-5/16 in. Semi-Framed                           57-1/2 in. x 70-5/16 in.
18                                                2-1/4 HP Router                                           2-1/4 HP
19                           12-Volt Lithium-Ion Cordless 3/8 in.                                    12-Volt 3/8 in.
20                                     12-Gauge 24-5/8 in. Strap                                 12-Gauge 24-5/8 in.
21                                        7-3/4 in. Wigan Ceiling                                         7-3/4 in. 
22                                                   1 qt. B-I-N                                               1 qt.
23                                    3/8 in. O.D. x 1/4 in. NPTF                            3/8 in. O.D. x 1/4 in. 
24                       2-1/2 in. Long x 5/8 in. Diameter Spring                  2-1/2 in. Long x 5/8 in. Diameter
25                                       1/4 x 3 in. Heat-Shrink                                         1/4 x 3 in.
26                                                4-White PVC End                                                   
27                                  41000 Series Non-Vented Range                                                   
28                                 Revival 1-Spray 5-Katalyst Air                                 1-Spray 5-Katalyst
29                                       180-Degree White Outdoor                                         180-Degree
30                                          3/8 x 3 Hand Scraped                                             3/8 x 3
31                                                     67-Qt. Jug                                            67-Qt. 
32                                            35-77-7/8 in. White                                      35-77-7/8 in.
33                                -16 tpi x 4 in. Stainless Steel                                    -16 tpi x 4 in.
34                                               3-21 degree Full                                        3-21 degree
```

I am not sure how should I tweak my regex in order to work with all the cases? I have also tried to split my regex into multiple lines, but did not help much either.

Here's how I tried it:

```
df$col2 = paste(str_extract_all(df$col1, '([[:digit:]]*\\.?\\/?[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+(in|ft|cu\\.[[:space:]]+ft)\\.[[:space:]]*[WHD]*[[:space:]]+x*[[:space:]]*)+'), collapse = ' ')]

df$col2[is.na(df$col2)] <- paste(str_extract_all(df$col1[df$col2], '[[:digit:]]*\\.?\\/?[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*\\-*(oz|lb|gal|Gal)\\.'), collapse = ' ')

df$col2[is.na(df$col2)] <- paste(str_extract_all(df$col1[df$col2],'[[:digit:]]*\\.?\\,?[[:digit:]]+\\-?[[:space:]]*(Watt|Pack|Gauge|piece|Piece|Panel|mph|MPH|cc|Ton|ton|Light|Gang|LED|Volt|amp|BTU|Amp|Drawer|Step|Tier|Cycle)[[:space:]]+'), collapse = ' ')

df$col2[is.na(df$col2)] <- paste(str_extract_all(df$col1[df$col2],,'[[:digit:]]*\\.?\\,?[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+sq\\.[[:space:]]+ft\\.'), collapse = ' ')
```

Yet, am not getting the results I would want.

Do you have any inputs?

Thanks!

Comment: this is _highly_ irregular -- your data is a mess. e.g., what are the units on 3/8 x 3 Hand Scrape?

Comment: I agree with you on irregularity of the data. There are some numbers that do not have any units at all and 3/8 x 3 Hand Scrape is one such example

Comment: Is this the full data? I really just recommend cleaning it by hand. Any regex that works will be a mile long, as far as I can tell.

Comment: No, the actual data is over millions of rows..and there are many more different patterns..I just scanned some by looking at them.